# MLE of multivariate normal distribution when the VCV matrix is full of equations

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, structural-equation-modeling, covariance-matrix, multivariate-normal-distribution

Short Version: Given a variance covariance matrix for my multivariate normal distribution where the entries are equations of other parameters, how do I find which of those parameter values maximizes the likelihood of my data?

I've tried treating the function which calculates the likelihood of my data like a black box and using bounded and unbounded versions of the optimization routines "Nelder-Mead", "BFGS", "CG", "L-BFGS-B", "SANN", nlminb","bobyqa","cobyla","Rvmmin","hjn", and "mlrMBO" to solve for the parameter values that make my data most likely.  But this approach has failed.  Instead, I want to try analytically solving the math equations, but I do not know how.

I am modelling the evolution of species along an evolutionary tree, where I use a path model (of SEM style [i.e. the type used in structural equation modelling]) to account for the fact that colder temperatures cause species to evolve thicker fur, with some temporal delay.  I explain it more below if you are interested, but it results in the following variance covariance matrix, where each entry is the covariance between the measured trait (fur thickness) of a particular species with the measured value of another trait (temperature) of a second species.  The traits have covariance because of their shared evolutionary history:[image: variance covariance matrix of multivariate normal distribution where the covariances are expressed in terms of other parameters]

I understand, as stated clearly on wikipedia, that
[image: Wikipedia Screenshot]

And thus, problem solved, except I have no idea how to take the log of my Sigma matrix, or it's inverse, or it's derivative, or multiply it by anything, or anything else for that matter.  Is there a way I could hand this covariance matrix off to some type of calculator along with the data vector and get a maximum likelihood parameter estimate?  And if not, what kind of manipulations do I need to do to get the equations into a form I can hand to a solver, I imagine calling something like `Solve()` in R (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/solve).  Also, I've heard optimization with mins and maxes can be very non-trivial.  Is this going to be an issue for me?  And if so, how would I monitor it?  The mins/maxs are mostly there because if the delay interval is too large or too small to for an interaction to occur within the span of a branch, then it's effect should be zero, so maybe they can be reworked to not exist in their current form somehow(?).

The final thing I'm confused by is how to deal with the mean?  the covariance matrix above gives the relationships among the changes in the trait values.  But in real life, species don't start at (0,0): (zero fur, zero temperature).  The actual ancestral value of the species might be (5,5) and then the evolved (BX,BY) trait will be (42,3.14), meaning the change  will be (42-5,3.14-5), and it's that change that is correlated with the changes in the other traits, but I don't know the original value of the species 10 million years ago, so that also needs to be estimated, or maybe I can fit the other parameters without estimating it?

So  all of that above is the question.  Thank your for your assistance.  For the curious, I include below the specific path model I am using to model the evolution of traits X and Y as well as the phylogeny/evolutionary tree that the species and their traits are evolving on.  The idea is that the observed Y value is the sum of the changes in each of the two Y values plus the initial value of the ancestor.  Similarly for X, except for this toy case, there is only one component of X.  The changes in the species' traits across time is modeled by Brownian motion and thus the covariance shared among their changes is proportional to the amount of time they've been coevolving together.
[image: The red numbers are the length (in time units) of the branches on the phylogeny]
[image: Two traits are being examined, X, and Y. This model gives the causal relationships between them as codified with path analysis.]

Comment: What do you want to estimate via MLE?

Comment: I want to estimate the parameters of the Brownian motion process that result in the variance-covariance structure given in the matrix above.  For example, for species A, B, and C, their observed X values will be the result of Brownian motion acting across the length of time from the common ancestor of species A, B, and C, up until the current moment in time when their X value is measured.  This Brownian motion has 3 parameters, it's variance, it's covariance with the Brownian motion process responsible for the evolution of Y0 and it's covariance with that for Yt. I also need Vy0 and Vyt.